# Are there any performance considerations when reading web.config AppSettings?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-api

I'm writing a REST service with Web Api. One of the actions reads an AppSetting value from the web.config during execution.

I would assume the web.config is loaded into memory, but during high load, does reading the setting have a noticeable performance impact? What are the best practices for doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357765/does-configurationmanager-appsettingskey-read-from-the-web-config-file-each-ti